# How to update an array everytime when pushing values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing difficulty while pushing the values inside the array.

Suppose I have array like this

`const arr = ["tom", "harry", "mike"];`

What I want to achieve is, when I am pushing values inside this array. I don't want to append that value in the array, but create a new array with the appended value and not change the old array.

Comment: Then us an assignment like `arr = ["new", "values"]`? You need to drop the `const` though and replace it with `var` or `let`.

Comment: what youre saying doesnt really make sense to me, please show code, what youve tried, or an example of what youare trying to do.

Comment: In React, instead of using Array.push(), you have to append using spread operator. const arr = [...arr, new_item], to make state update. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Push is meant to be modify the array so I think you can take advantage of spread operator to create new array with new value added instead of modifying the old one.

```js
let arr = ["j", "d", "s"];
let newFrontAdd = ["new value", ...arr]
let newRearAdd = [ ...arr, "new value"]

console.log("original array : ", arr);
console.log("added value at front : ", newFrontAdd);
console.log("added value at rear : ", newRearAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about arrays is here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

When talking about arrays, the term `push` means to append.

```js
const arr = ["tom", "harry", "mike"];
arr.push("swapnil")
// arr: ["tom", "harry", "mike", "swapnil"]
```

If you want to set a particular index, you may do that like so:

```js
const arr = ["tom", "harry", "mike"];
arr[1] = "swapnil"
// arr: ["tom", "swapnil", "mike"]
```

If you'd like to overwrite the entire array, you can't use `const`. Use `let` (or `var`) instead.

```js
let arr = ["tom", "harry", "mike"];
arr = ["swapnil", "steve]
// arr: ["swapnil", "steve"]
```